# How To Create Every Unique Combination of X Arrays Include Y number of Items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

The question in the title is the one that I've seen on SO before many times, and I like to share my code snipped to do that. If anyone has any improvements, I like to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arraySet = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7],
  [8,9,10],
  [11,12],
  [13,14,15]
]

// We need to know how many unique combinations can be created.
// In this example it's 216.
let outputArrayLength = 1;
arraySet.forEach(array => {
  outputArrayLength = outputArrayLength * array.length
});

// Let's create the output array that contains empty arrays for now.
// The number of items should be equal to outputArrayLength;
let outputArray = Array.from(Array(outputArrayLength), () => []);

// To fill the empty arrays properly, we need to know 3 things.
// 1. How many iterations are needed per item?
//    We need to calculate the number of unique combinations of the arrays before the current one.
// 2. How many times should that item be pushed in each iteration?
//    We need to calculate the number of unique combinations of the arrays after the current one.
// For example, when we reached the 3rd array, which is [8,9,10] in the loop,
// each array item will be pushed 6 (2 * 3) times in each iteration of 12 (4 * 3).
// 3. Does the current item belong to which array in outputArray?
//    By incrementing lastIndex after each item push, we will know which array is our new target.
let previousCombinations = 1;
let remaningCombinations = outputArrayLength;
let lastIndex = 0;

arraySet.forEach(array => {
  // Calculate 2
  remaningCombinations = remaningCombinations / array.length;
  // Push the item to the target array.
  for (let i = 0; i < previousCombinations; i++) {
   array.forEach(num => {
    for (let i = 0; i < remaningCombinations; i++) {
        outputArray[lastIndex].push(num);
       if (lastIndex < outputArrayLength -1) {
         lastIndex++; 
       } else {
         lastIndex = 0;
       }
     }
   }) 
  }
  // Calculate 1 before the next loop.
  previousCombinations = previousCombinations * array.length;
})

console.log(outputArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a different(?) approach.
Basically, counting from 0 to choices product, and converting to a "number" with each "digit" with it's own "base"...

```js
var arr=[
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7],
  [8,9,10],
  [11,12],
  [13,14,15]
];
var lengths=arr.map(subArr=>subArr.length);
var lengthsProd=lengths.reduce((acc,cv)=>acc*cv,1);
var masterIndexes=[];

for(var i=0; i<lengthsProd; i++) {
  var indexes=[];
  var index=i;
  for(var j=lengths.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
    var jlength=lengths[j];
    indexes.unshift(index%jlength);
    index=Math.floor(index/jlength);
  }
  masterIndexes.push(indexes);
};

var combinations=masterIndexes.map(index=>
  index.map((i, idx)=>arr[idx][i])
);

console.log("masterIndexes:");
console.log(masterIndexes.join(", "));
//masterIndexes.forEach(mi=>console.log(mi.join(", ")));
console.log("-".repeat(50));
console.log("combinations:");
console.log(combinations.join(", "));
//combinations.forEach(c=>console.log(c.join(", ")));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I tried to create something like your masterIndexes and failed. It's nice to see how it can be done. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help = you are welcome!
Accept?  Up-vote? :)